# OpenCV play 2 videos same time

Tags: opencv, video

I would like to present two videos at the same time. The following code is working, but somehow it has an error occurs when the videos are finished. If I only play one video, the error does not occur. Any help?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string filename1 = "C:/test_videos/toy_plane_liftoff.avi";
    string filename2 = "C:/test_videos/toy_plane_liftoff_stab.avi";

    VideoCapture capture1(filename1);
    VideoCapture capture2(filename2);

    Mat frame1, frame2;

    if (!capture1.isOpened())
        throw "Error1";
    if (!capture2.isOpened())
        throw "Error2";
    for (int i = 0; i <= min(capture1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT), capture2.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)); i++)
    {
        capture1 >> frame1;
        capture2 >> frame2;

        imshow("1", frame1);
        imshow("2", frame2);

        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) 
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get rid of the error in the following way

```
    if( !frame1.empty())
    imshow("1", frame1);
    if( !frame2.empty())
    imshow("2", frame2);
```